# How to find topographic distance of molecule from mol format

Tags: rdkit, cheminformatics, drug-design

I have written this code using RdKit to find topographic distance

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import rdDistGeom as molDG
dm=AllChem.Get3DDistanceMatrix('example.mol')
print(dm)
```

I'm not quite sure if the general form of the code is correct, but it also leads to an error message I don't know how to fix.

```
AllChem.Get3DDistanceMatrix('example.mol')
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    rdkit.Chem.rdmolops.Get3DDistanceMatrix(str)
did not match C++ signature:
    Get3DDistanceMatrix(class RDKit::ROMol {lvalue} mol, int confId=-1, bool useAtomWts=False, bool force=False, char const * __ptr64 prefix='')
```

I would like some help either correcting this error or just getting an example of computing topographic distance with rdkit.

Answer (score 5):

First off, it's important to know that some (most?) mol files do not include 3D coordinates. So you'd need to generate them (e.g., from `rdDistGeom` or ETKDG).

Your problem is that you're supplying a filename string to a method that requires a molecule object.

Let's assume your `example.mol` file has 3D coordinates already.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import rdDistGeom as molDG
 
mol = Chem.MolFromMolFile('example.mol')
# either of these should work
bm = molDG.GetMoleculeBoundsMatrix(mol)
# .. or what you asked
dm = AllChem.Get3DDistanceMatrix(mol)
```

If (more likely) you need to generate 3D coordinates, you'll want something like this:

```
mol = Chem.MolFromMolFile('example.mol')
# always add hydrogens before generating 3D coordinates
m2 = Chem.AddHs(mol)
AllChem.EmbedMolecule(m2)
# if you don't want to consider the hydrogens you can remove them
# before calculating the distance matrix
dm = AllChem.Get3DDistanceMatrix(mol)
```

Comment: Can the above code rewritten to use for SDF files or XYZ files. As  it will have the 3D coordinates I feel sir.

Comment: A SDF and Mol are essentially the same. They do not necessarily have 3D coordinates. If you know your particular files have 3D coordinates, great. But most don't. At the moment, I do not believe XYZ is natively supported by RDKit, although the next release should.

Comment: Kindly advice me on which type of file is useful for 3D for now

Comment: @sriram - that seems like another question, rather than something to discuss in the comments, thanks.